# How to set up a Jenkins item using Jenkinsfile, to checkout from git to USS, build, test and deploy?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, mainframe

I'm looking for an example of using Jenkinsfile to checkout from git, build and deploy on z/OS?

I have Jenkins running on Linux server, with the z/OS plugins.

Looking for some best practices on setting up Jenkinsfile for z/OS.

Answer (score 2):

A Jenkinsfile pipeline script is groovy code.  Groovy is essentially interpreted Java and Java relies on the JVM which is OS-agnostic.

Pipeline syntax is a groovy Domain Specific Language (DSL)

If you have the pipeline set of plugins installed, you should be able to follow the documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started) and [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline) to achieve whatever you need to.

Comment: Thank you, The question was more directed for how to or examples of setting Jenkinsfiles to run on z/OS using only open source tools.  So, using Jenkinsfile to checkout from Git, using z/OS Jenkin's slave, converting it from ASCII to EBCDIC, building, testing and deploying.  Not Cobol, but Java.

Comment: If its just Java code, then why do you need to convert it to EBCDIC? Are you calling into the ISPF gateway at all?

Comment: RocketGit can handle the converstion of EBCDIC to ASCII and vice versa. Its open source.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample pipeline script that you can use to checkout code from Git using the Jenkins slave on z/OS -

```
def scmvars = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [],gitTool: 'GitDBB', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: ‘<cred>’ url: ‘<repo>’]]])
```

You can also refer to vars like the git_commit etc. by using scmvars.GIT_COMMIT and so on. This will checkout into a USS directory and you can then invoke your java build scripts.

The gitTool here refers to the script that does the conversion between ASCII and EBCDIC.It has been defined under the Jenkins Global Tool configuration. It contains the iconv scripts to convert git commands. I have attached a sample called git-jenkins.sh -

```
#! /bin/sh

if test -n "$GIT_SSH" ; then
  dbbtmp=~/${JOB_NAME}@dbb
  if ! test -d "$dbbtmp" ; then
    mkdir $dbbtmp
    createdDbbTmp=true
  fi
  cat $GIT_SSH | iconv -f utf-8 -T -t IBM-1047 > $dbbtmp/git.ssh.sh
  export GIT_KEY=$(cat $dbbtmp/git.ssh.sh | grep ssh | sed "s/key.*/key/" | sed    "s/.* .//")
  cat $GIT_KEY | iconv -f utf-8 -T -t IBM-1047 > $dbbtmp/git.ssh.key
  rm -f $GIT_SSH
  cp $dbbtmp/git.ssh.sh $GIT_SSH
  chmod 700 $GIT_SSH
  rm -f $GIT_KEY
  cp $dbbtmp/git.ssh.key $GIT_KEY
  chmod 600 $GIT_KEY
  if test "$createdDbbTmp" = true ; then
    rm -rf $dbbtmp
  fi
fi
git "$@" | iconv -f ibm-1047 -t ibm-1047
```

Please make sure you FTP up the above script in such a way to convert to EBCDIC.  Or tag it as ASCII in USS. Instructions on how to use the shell script when configuring the Jenkins remote agent can be found at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6T76_1.0.2/jenkinsintegration.html    Please note the following from there:
-  The shell script requires that the Java options for the agent include "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"
-  Follow the steps outlined in the "Node Properties: Check "Tool Locations" section for having the agent use the script.

For build - I have used the following to run my build groovy scripts for building the files (Cobol in my case) -

```
println RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy("""
    def command = '$groovyt' + '$classp' + '$scriptname' + '$parm'
    println command
    def p = command.execute()
    p.waitFor()
    println p.in.text
    """, Jenkins.instance.slaves.find { it.name == node }.channel)
 }
```

Hope these samples help!